# Power BI report server (Aug 2018 upgrade issue)

Tags: power-bi-report-server

I was using Power BI report server version March 2018, after upgrade to version August 2018, dashboards don't load properly, does anyboday has the same issue?
The current version is 15.0.2.557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried clearing the browser cache on the user clients? Had a similar issue where the dashboard would never load and that resolved it.